# Json in auth file of firebase is not loading

Tags: javascript, json, ubuntu, firebase

Using this [file](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/exampletokengenerator/auth.html) for generating the token on firebase on my computer but .json not working. This directory is placed on my desktop and file is on the same path/folder. Can anyone tell why it is not loading? I have the second laptop and on that, this file is working fine.I am using ubuntu on both pc only difference is the ubuntu versions.

Comment: handleFileSelect is the main function

Comment: **No JSON file found!** is shown in console